# apache RewriteRule not working on server but works on local xampp

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have problem with my rewrite rules for apache. This url not working on server but works on my xampp:

http://www.kajak-zveza.si/moduli/novice/jure-meglic-mora-ponovno-pod-noz

my rewrite rule

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^moduli/([^/]+)/(.*)$ moduli/$1/index.php/$2 [L]
```

but this works:

http://www.kajak-zveza.si/moduli/novice/index.php/jure-meglic-mora-ponovno-pod-noz

why? what is wrong that works on xampp but not on server with php 5.3.8

Comment: RewriteEngine is ON and file has755 permissions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure in your Apache conf you have

```
<Directory /path/to/your/site/dir>
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
#RewriteLog "/var/log/apache2/rewrite.log"
#RewriteLogLevel 3
```

then tail -f the `/var/log/apache2/rewrite.log` file.
Watch this file closely when you make the failed request, also the Apache error log.

Then, when the problem is fixed, make sure you use the right permissions in the `Directory` directive above.